# Google OAuth in MVC 4 gives Multiple Tokes for same domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0

I've got a fresh MVC 4 internet template with OAuth 2.  The application is deployed to an internet domain (somedomain.com) and successfully logs users in through google oauth.  However subsequent login attempts will keep asking the user to authorize access to their email address as if it was the first time even though "remember my decision" is selected.  Looking at my [Google AuthSubTokens](https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens) shows multiple instances of somedomain.com.

Any ideas on why google will keep asking for authorization?

Comment: if I am not mistaken google's out of the box provider is oauth and not oauth2. which library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Google gives different tokens for http:// and https:// for the same account. Maybe that is your issue.